# Flask-python caching

Tags: python, caching, flask

I am doing API for my app using flask. It is like, suppose you query the API, it will give a list of 100 items as a response. I need to show first 10 to the users and save rest 90 in cache, so when user swiped those first 10 items, I will display next 11-20 items and so on..

The problem I am facing is to where store those 90 items and retrieve them using API. I am thinking of doing this using varnish as cache to store responses. I want to know is varnish a good fit here? If yes then How? or Is there any better way to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Try redis https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-redis-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not really what Varnish is for; it's more for caching complete pages.

A better fit here would be memcached, which is perfect for storing arbitrary data against a key. Redis could be another alternative.